# Converting string to timestamp in DB2 with to many fractions of a second

Tags: db2

I am trying to convert a string on the on the following format to a timestamp in DB2: 2015-09-07T09:15:25.4788396+04:00

Problem is, DB2 only seems to handle 6 digit fractional seconds, not 7 as in my case. Any thoughts on a good workaround?

Comment: can't you just truncate?

Comment: Well... I would prefer not to lose the timezone information at the end of the string.

Comment: what language are you programming in? or do you want to do this in db2 itself, which I do not recommend.

Comment: I am doing it in DB2 yes (while parsing an XML wich is allready in the database).

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Answer (score 2):

The format you have there matches the `xs:dateTime` pattern from XML. You can use this to your advantage and use implied XML parsing:

```
SELECT XMLCAST(XMLCAST('2015-09-07T09:15:25.4788396+04:00' AS XML) AS TIMESTAMP)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

            1
--------------------------
2015-09-07-05:15:25.478839
```

Note the timestamp returned is in UTC, add `+ CURRENT TIMEZONE` to return it as a local timestamp. Tested on DB2 z/OS DSN10015.

Comment: `1)` There is no DB2 z/OS 9.7. There is 9.1 and 10. Your answer does work on the z/OS 10 instance I tested, but does not work on LUW 9.7. `2)` On the z/OS instance I tried, your answer truncates off the fractional second's last digit. You can fix this by doing `TIMESTAMP(7)` instead of `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the timezone from the string.  Once you have that you can get the UTC time from subtracting from "current timezone" then add the parsed timezone to it as shown below.  You will also need to use REPLACE to change T to a dash and colons to dots.

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP('2015-09-07-09.15.25.4788396') - (current timezone)) + 4 hours FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Comment: How does he get the substring then? And how does he know that the timezone offset is 4h?